# Random number generator without repeating numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, random, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a random number generator without repeating numbers {0 - 7}.

im getting a seg fault error here, and im pretty sure im allocating all the memory correctly there. One solution that i found that works occasionally is if i set shuffledbracket parameter size to 9. however since it has one extra memory it puts in an extra 0. any ideas on how i could get my array to only have a parameter size of 8 without a seg fault error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`8` is not a valid index into `shuffledbracket` the indices of a C++ array are `0 to N-1`, in this case `0 to 7`, so you need to modify your loop:

```
for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
           ^^^    ^^^
```

this introduces another problem since modulus by `0` is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

```
randnumero = rand()%i;
                   ^^
```

If you want to generate a random number from `[M,N]` you can use this formula from the [C FAQ entry How can I get random integers in a certain range?](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html):

```
M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1)
```

or you could use the [random header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) and [uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution):

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, i);
```

Comment: As he explained, modulus by zero is undefined behavior.

Comment: just to double check what i posted above works as well right?

Comment: @user3298889 it should work fine but for future reference the above methods are better.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in `C++` start from `0`. Therefore your `for` loop is invalid. Instead of:

```
for (int i = 8; i > 0; i--)
```

It should be

```
for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
```

Besides that, there's obviously no `hehe` variable.

Comment: Of course it returns a floating point exception error - the last iteration will do `rand()%0`. You have to change that line.

Comment: got it, i just did rand()%(i+1).